# Toggle class on a mapped element in react

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and I have some doubts about changing the color onClick
How can I toggle the className of a `<p>`  element that is being clicked? At the moment clicking on one changes the color on everything.

I have read about passing a state on a parent element but at this point is getting a bit confusing and if someone could help me clarifying this would be nice.

Here's the code of my child element:

```
import "./Answer.scss";

function Answer(props) {
  const getAnswers = [];
  const correct_answer = props.correct_answer;
  getAnswers.push(correct_answer);

  for (let i = 0; i < props.incorrect_answers.length; i++) {
    getAnswers.push(props.incorrect_answers[i]);
  }

  const [answers, setAnswer] = useState(getAnswers);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

  const displayAnswers = answers.map((answer, index) => (
    <p
      className={active ? "answer" : "answer-active"}
      key={index}
      onClick={() => setActive((prevState) => !prevState)}
    >
      {answer.replace(/&quot;|&#039;/g, '"')}
    </p>
  ));

  return <div className="answer-box">{displayAnswers}</div>;
}

export default Answer;
```

And this is the parent:

```
import Answer from "../Answer/Answer";

function Questions(props) {
  const questions = props.questions.map((question, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="question" key={index}>
        <h2>{question.question.replace(/&quot;|&#039;/g, '"')}</h2>
        <Answer
          incorrect_answers={question.incorrect_answers}
          correct_answer={question.correct_answer}
        />
        <hr></hr>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="questions-container">{questions}</div>;
}

export default Questions;
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
const [answers, setAnswer] = useState(getAnswers);
const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

const displayAnswers = answers.map((answer, index) => (
  <p
    className={active ? "answer" : "answer-active"}
    key={index}
    onClick={() => setActive((prevState) => !prevState)}
  >
    {answer.replace(/&quot;|&#039;/g, '"')}
  </p>
));
```

You are iterating your answers and updating the same state variable for each answer. It's like you are over-writing the updated values. Instead, you can make a separate state variable for each and every option. Based on the `onClick`, you can update that specific answer state and use it in the code. Check the below code.

```
const AnswerText = ({ valid, index, answer }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(valid);
  return (
    <p
      className={active ? "answer" : "answer-active"}
      key={index}
      onClick={() => setActive((prevState) => !prevState)}
    >
      {answer}
    </p>
  );
};
```

You can use the above component in the map and display your answers.

Attached is a sandbox for reference.

[image: Edit reverent-glitter-d9yxce]